# Issues with locale for shiny app

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, shiny

I am writing a shiny app on my local computer (ISO-8859-1 is system default encoding). When I save ui.R with this encoding and I try to run the app an error related to non-UTF-8 encoding creeps up. So, I save the file with UTF-8 encoding and the app works **if I don't have special characters in the file**.

The *special* characters are mexican accents (á, é, í, ó) which supposedly are supported by UTF-8.

If I save the file with UTF-8 and open it again, I get these characters translated into rubbish (?A, etc).

I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] broom_0.4.1       knitr_1.15.1      data.table_1.10.0 reshape2_1.4.2    RODBC_1.3-14      tse.sql_0.1.0    
 [7] memisc_0.99.7-1   MASS_7.3-45       lattice_0.20-34   foreign_0.8-67    magrittr_1.5      ggplot2_2.2.1    
[13] inegiR_1.2.0      dplyr_0.5.0       tse.utils_0.1.0   shiny_0.14.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zoo_1.7-13         splines_3.3.2      colorspace_1.2-7   sourcetools_0.1.5  htmltools_0.3.5    yaml_2.1.14       
 [7] mgcv_1.8-15        base64enc_0.1-3    XML_3.98-1.5       nloptr_1.0.4       DBI_0.5-1          plyr_1.8.4        
[13] stringr_1.1.0      MatrixModels_0.4-1 munsell_0.4.3      gtable_0.2.0       psych_1.6.9        evaluate_0.10     
[19] SparseM_1.74       httpuv_1.3.3       quantreg_5.29      pbkrtest_0.4-6     parallel_3.3.2     Rcpp_0.12.7       
[25] xtable_1.8-2       scales_0.4.1       backports_1.0.4    jsonlite_1.2       mime_0.5           lme4_1.1-12       
[31] mnormt_1.5-5       digest_0.6.10      stringi_1.1.2      grid_3.3.2         rprojroot_1.1      tools_3.3.2       
[37] lazyeval_0.2.0     tibble_1.2         tidyr_0.6.0        car_2.1-4          Matrix_1.2-7.1     assertthat_0.1    
[43] minqa_1.2.4        rmarkdown_1.3      R6_2.2.0           nnet_7.3-12        nlme_3.1-128
```

Comment: When opening it again, do you make sure that you're opening with UTF-8 encoding only? Try `File > Reopen with encoding` option on Rstudio.

Comment: this did it! So annoying! Thanks Ujjwal! And sorry for the simple question..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4395383/ujjwal-kumar). Seems like an rstudio thing, just tried reopening with another encoding...